# JS issues, trying to add a space between words

Tags: javascript

I am having a little issue with my JS code.

I have written the below but i cant seem to add spaces between the words?

```
var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
var values = textareas [0].value ;
var vals = values.s
var result =  ""

for (i = 0 ; i < vals. length ; i ++ ) {
   if (vals [i] == '') {

  }
}

textareas[1].value = result;
```

as you can see that there are spaces between the numbers which would need to match the word spacings?

the text area is a HTML element, and i want to add spaces between the words so it pastes

## this them their

instead of

## thisthemtheir in the text area

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate? What's exactly in your ```textarea``` and what's your expected output after doing all these?

Comment: Do you want to add spaces or remove spaces? Is "42,54..., ,4" the text in the textarea?

Comment: hi can you explain more? give the expected output and the actual output at least please since I do not understand the question fully. You say that you are unable to add spaces to your words, but when I run your program, it returns "this them " which clearly has words separated by spaced

Comment: the text area is a HTML element, and i want to add spaces between the words so it pastes this them their instead of thisthemtheir in the text area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is that if you have spaces in the source text (i.e. between the numbers), you need a space in the comparison.  So, it should be:

> if (vals [i] == ' ')

and not

> if (vals [i] == '')

Also, change the line:

> result += [ ]

to read

> result += ' '

Here it is working with spaces:

```js
    var values = "42,54,53,43, ,42,54,57,49" ;
    var vals = values.split(",");
    var result =  ""

    for (i = 0 ; i < vals. length ; i ++ ) {
       if (vals [i] == ' ') {
        result += ' '
      } else {
       result += String.fromCharCode (31 + 127 - parseInt (vals [i]));
      }
    }

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have done that and it has removed all spaces when i needed spaces like the picture above?
if (vals [i] == ' ')   this seemed to remove the spaces?